# Show that if $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ injective then there exists $S \in \mathcal{L}(W,V)$ such that $ST$ is the identity map on $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, linear-transformations

> Let $W$ be a finite-dimensional and $T\in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$. Show that if $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ injective then there exists $S \in \mathcal{L}(W,V)$ such that $ST$ is the identity map on $V$. I saw some posts on this statement but I didn't find the same approach as mine. If someone could give a feedback on my proof, I would really appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

As $T\in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ is injective, then by fundamental theorem of linear maps we have that $\dim V=\dim \text{null}\ T+\dim \text{range}\ T=0+\dim \text{range}\ T\le \dim W$. So, $\dim V\le \dim W$.

Let $(v_1,...,v_n)$ be a basis of $V$ and $(w_1,...,w_m)$ be a basis of $W$ (so $n\le m$). Define $T$ and $S$ as the following:

$T(v_i)=w_i, S(w_i)=v_i$ with $i=1,...,n$.

Both $T$ and $S$ are well defined as $n\le m$. Thus, $ST(v_i)=S(w_i)=v_i$which is exactly an identity map as each $v\in V$ can be expressed uniquely.

Comment: It might help you to see that $T: V \rightarrow T (V)$ is bijective linear map, so there linear map $S$ defined in $T(V)$ such that $ ST: V \rightarrow V $ is the identity operator.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you don't get to define $T$, it's given to you in the problem. Here's similar approach to yours:

Let $\{ v_i \mid i \in I \}$ be a basis for $V$. Then because $T$ is injective, $\{ T(v_i) \mid i \in I \}$ is a linearly independent set in $W$. Extend it to a basis $\{ T(v_i) \mid i \in I \} \cup \{ w_j \mid j \in J \}$ of $W$, and define $S : W \to V$ on this basis by sending $S(T(v_i)) = v_i$ for all $i \in I$, and $S(w_j) = 0$ for all $j \in J$. Then $S \circ T = \text{id}_V$ since these two maps $V \to V$ agree on the basis $\{v_i\}$.

Note that this does not require either $V$ or $W$ to be finite-dimensional!

Comment: I just tried to remake my proof and compare with yours. I did nearly everything same as in your proof. But, instead of considering that $T(v_i)$ is linearly independent in $W$ I did the following: I remarked that $\dim V= \dim \text{range} \ T$ so I considered the basis of the image separately with the same dimension as $V$ and extended it to the basis of $W$ as range $ T$ is a subspace of $W$. Is it correct, please? I just didn’t use the fact that  $T(v_i)$ is linearly independent in $W$. Does it change something to the proof?

Comment: Can you answer, please?

Comment: You haven’t quite given enough information for me to tell if your proof is correct. How did you define $S$?

Answer (score 1):

The point is that every subspace $W'$ of $W$ has at least one **complement**, i.e. a subspace $W''$ of $W$ such that $W$ is the direct sum of $W'$ and $W''$.  This means that every $w \in W$ can be expressed uniquely as $w' + w''$ for $w' \in W'$ and $w'' \in W''$.

So if $W'$ is the image of $T$, the injectivity of $T$ implies that for each $w' \in W'$, there is a unique $v_{w'} \in V$ such that $T(v_{w'}) = w'$.  Now for $w = w'+w'' \in W$, define

$$S(w) = v_{w'}.$$
Then $S$ is a linear map with the required properties.